# How to detect on my API sever if API request is coming from a chrome extension?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, google-chrome-extension, browser

I am using Laravel on my API server.
I am making an API request from my chrome extension.
Since I couldn't find a way to save my API auth token safely in the chrome extension and reuse it every time I want to make a request, hence I am looking for a way to identify the request on API side if the request is from my extension or not.

Comment: Have your extension send a custom header of some kind. Be aware that a malicious attacker could deconstruct your extension and simulate this; it won't be a perfect bit of protection.

Comment: @ceejayoz There is no custom header as of now

Comment: Sure. You have to do that. Update your extension to send one.

Comment: Use `method: 'POST'` or PUT and Chrome will add a secure header `Origin` automatically which can't be spoofed by web pages (other extensions can do it though, AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra header in the chrome extension where you are calling your Api .Add the header to api header when calling. Now in the controller use.

```
if ($request->hasHeader('X-Header-Name')) {
    Api call from extension ..
}
```

Reference Link [Request Header](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#request-headers)